# Separate site for Catholics and Protestants

Tags: discussion, site-definition, catholicism

I was going through the different discussions and could see mix of responses from Catholics and Protestants. This creates a huge confusion in the discussion as the fundamentals of both denominations are different. Due to this responses in discussions are creating confusion as you see references to traditions and opinions as opposed to facts. In matter of faith the fundamental positions are important and if not in agreement then it's irrelevant on agreeing on minor or superficial points. Having different sites will keep the discussions relevant and short. Other members can share their opinion on this.

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the questions that have mixed responses please? Questions should be scoped to a denomination to prevent this so it looks like bad questions or that someone who answered the question decided to give their perspective rather than the one requested. Note this is not a discussion site but a Q and A site.

Comment: This Is Not A Discussion Site. This is a Q&A site in the SE network. Please take a look at [How We Are Different From Other Sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204). Welcome.

Comment: @Belinda Tagging and scoping the question is recommended as a way to ask a proper question. I have noticed that questions asked are very general and tagging for a response from a denomination is not followed. So it can be answered by people with different world views. I can point instances of this. How do I post it as examples?

Comment: Just [edit] your question to add links and flag the questions if you feel that they are unclear.

Comment: I think this is a pretty fair comment. Even though you will get a variety of responses to any given question, even if you limit yourself to posters calling themselves Catholic, Catholicisim in particular is remarkably easy to pin down on at least the easiest questions of fact. The same is just not true of most other Christian traditions except maybe Orthodoxy (I've never tried, and I don't have the same expectation of clarity of the Orthodox Church, but I assume that on 99.999% of questions they're Catholic too).

Comment: @user33779 Can you give an example of how the fundamentals are different? As a matter of (even historical) fact, Protestants *are* Christians through faith and baptism and they have a sacramental relationship with the Church so in the end the differences are not substantial, as it were. But *culturally* Protestantism is indeed fundamentally different from the Catholic-Orthodox Tradition and maybe that's important in a text-only environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love that to be the case,  the problem is, when this site got started on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) , the ["powers that be"](https://stackexchange.com) rolled up 3 or 4 disparate sites into this one.

I followed the Catholicism site proposal, but not this one, although I am the first user on this site and find it a great place to ask questions about the Catholic Church, and it eventually became filled with knowledgeable folks.

As a Catholic, I found that my answers to "general Christianity" questions, especially biblical interpretation questions were not held in very high regard and this site became more a of popularity contest.

The moderation crew, and the people who frequent this meta-site, also realized that and attempted to make it clear that most, if not all, questions require some form of scoping to make it clear who *you* want answers from.  That comes in the form of both tagging, and clearly asking for the scope of who you want answers from in the question.

If the answers provided do not come from the point of view of the question asked, they can be flagged by users and will more than likely be deleted.

If the questions you mentioned say "Locked" or "Closed", then these questions have already been determined to be questions that cannot be reasonably answered from a defined point of view within Christianity.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply. I'm a newbie to the site and hence found that the lack of categorization confusing. There would be time lost moderating due to the simple step and users would spend extra time scoping and tagging. I had a tag removed from my original post after edit though I felt it was appropriate. Here it becomes subjective to the moderator's opinion.

Comment: "As a Catholic, I found that my answers to "general Christianity" questions, especially biblical interpretation questions were not held in very high regard and this site became more a of **popularity contest**." Unfortunately, as an independent Protestant, I feel that it still is.

Comment: @abs I sympathize, and after lots of sympathizing, I think there should be yet another site where answers can be evaluated on their own merit.   It's not unheard of for making several sites on the same topic in the StackExchange network, we've already got hermenuetics.   I tried to start a Catholic Culture site last summer, but it didn't get too far.  About 1/3rd of the way through commitment.

Comment: I become more sorry by the day. It seems to me that this site should be rolled into Biblical Hermeneutics; I fail to see the difference...

Answer (score 4):

### Pay Attention To The Tags on Questions to Avoid Confusion.

I strongly suggest that you pay close attention to the tags under each question.  That will prevent most of the confusion.

1. If the question is tagged "Catholicism" then any answer worthy of a
   vote has to come from a Catholic point of view.
2. If the question is tagged "Reformed" or "Anglican" or "Presbyterian" (and so on, lots of denominations) then any answer will have to come from that PoV.

   I can't emphasize this enough: Pay Attention To The Tags.  It's been very helpful to me to do so, and I think it will be helpful to you.

#### Christians disagree on a lot of fine detail

Because there is a lot of difference in interpretation between the denominations, this sire requires that answers (in most cases) and questions clarify which Christian denomination's interpretation or teaching is being asked about.  To not do that creates confusion, and a lousy signal to noise ratio.

#### [This is an SE site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204)

The whole purpose of SE sites it to provide Questions [and Answers that have a high signal to noise ratio](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6103/24204).  That's why the above is done.

#### Did I mention the tags?

Please make sure you read the tags associated with each question.

Comment: Thanks Korvin. I will use the tagging option you have suggested.