# Suggestions about getting a different denomination to answer? Not just for the asker but also for the (potential) answerer

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46565/does-the-catholic-church-endorse-the-children-of-narcissistic-parents-breaking-o) I asked a question for Catholicism. [Obviously](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/are-we-ready-for-catholicism-se/), no Catholic answer (until like 3.5 years after 1st bounty).

1 - it is forbidden if i asked without regard to a denomination (or without regard to biblical basis, but never mind this for now I guess) right? if so let's proceed. if not [are you kidding me](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth)?!?!

2 -  But there was a mormon who commented like i can give a mormon answer. lucky there was a mormon who came across my question. i imagine most mormons will just look at only the mormon tag.

2.1 - is there a way to attract more than 1 denomination to a question?

2.2 - can i just ask a question by denomination and then after awhile (2 days, same as bounty), instead of a bounty, i can just keep reposting questions with change of denomination? and in this case, how do you suggest i guess what denomination is likely to respond? (I guess [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-is-mainstream-christianity)?)

2.3 - wait actually...why again can't I just ask a truth question and then people give their own answers by denomination? Because there can't be an accepted answer?

Comment: no -1, from me on this, but I'm really not sure what you're asking.  A question really deserves one answer to be of optimal usefulness.  The site is about connecting people with good answers in perpetuity (making a catechism) not a snapshot of what people are thinking at the start of Christ's 3rd millennium.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately your question's subject matter is not a good fit for this site. Very few denominations make official pronouncements on single approaches to pastoral or psychological matters like this. Most church denominations will say that the best course of action in a case like this (a person with severely narcissistic/sociopathic parents) will depend on the advice of the person's (secular) psychologist or counsellor, along with the local church's pastoral principles and capacities. There's no right answer: for some people breaking off all contact may be best, for others, there may be the potential of reconciliation. The church may be able to help by sending people to attend mediation sessions with the parents, or they may not have anyone suitable for that. The psychologist may recommend a brief period of no contact, they may recommend low contact, or they may recommend persisting in contact. And all of the complexities mean that even if a denomination had made a singular pronouncement of all time, why would you trust it? These situations don't have single answers, so if anyone tries to say there is one, the only thing you can be sure of is that it won't be right some of the time.